# How to compare three sets of 'paired' categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, paired-data

I am sorry I do not have the right terminology to ask as clearly as I would like.

I have three datasets of biomes. Each gives a biome by latitude and longitude (3 biome maps converted to tables). The biome scheme used in each one is the same so they are comparable i.e. biome 1 means the same thing in every dataset. There are up to 27 biomes in each dataset.

I have combined them into one table by latitude and longitude so only lat-lon pairs with data from all three datasets are present (no missing data).

What I want to do is find out which datasets are most alike, or how correlated they are by lat-lon, so the data is paired.

I also want to be able to expand this analysis to include more datasets, as I am waiting on another two. None of the questions I have read seem to match my combination of categorical data, more than two samples, and paired.

Can anyone recommend a type of analysis for this situation? If it is relevant, I am doing the work in R.

Thank you.

Comment: I would approach this with a modification of Bayesian Gaussian processes with mixed effects for the distinct samples. The categorical variables could be related to the Gaussian process via a Dirichlet distribution.